# Adding CustomTaskPane without pane options

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto

I have a CustomTaskPane in Outlook which I'm adding with following code in C#:

`var pane = Globals.TrackingAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new MyControl(), " ");
pane.DockPosition = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
pane.Width = 700;`

And in Outlook it looks like this:
[Current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEu2I.png)

Is it possible to hide buttons marked in red (pane options and close?) I tried setting negative margin to the control and various values of `DockPositionRestrict`, but it doesn't change anything. I'd like my control to be shown immediately below the ribbon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the buttons cannot be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Custom Task Panes - there is no trivial way to hide thease controls.

But instead of using custom task panes you may consider using [Advanced Outlook Form Regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php). Or just use Windows API for subclassing Outlook windows, see [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information. The [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) sample code in C++ is available.